# Large query, multiple tables, old vs new JOIN syntax

Tags: oracle, join, syntax, ansi-sql

I have a large query that joins around 20 tables (mostly outer joins). It is using the older join syntax with commas and where conditions with (+) for outer joins. 
We noticed that it is consuming a lot of server memory. We are trying several things among which one idea is to convert this query to use the newer ANSI syntax, since the ANSI syntax allows better control on the order of JOINs and also specifies the JOIN predicates explicitly as they are applied.

Does converting the query from an older syntax to the newer ANSI syntax help in reducing the amount of data processed, for such large queries spanning a good number of tables?

Comment: Usually I'd say no, this shouldn't affect performance - unless you're using the Cost-Based Optimizer.
Which Oracle version are you using? Could you post the query?

Comment: Thank you all guys. You helped us save some time so we didnt put our immediate focus on the not-so-critical area. In the long term, we plan to move to the ANSI syntax. Also, appreciate other suggestions about reducing the server memory requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, it does not - it generates identical execution plans. That said, the newer JOIN syntax does allow you to things that you can't do with the old syntax. I would recommend converting it for that reason, and for clarity. The ANSI syntax is just so much easier to read (at least for me). Once converted you can then compare execution plans.

Comment: +1 for clarity - ANSI syntax is so much cleaner (apart from allowing additional things like full outer joins etc)

Answer (score 0):

DCookie said all there is to say about ANSI syntax.

However, if you outer join 20 tables, it is no wonder you will consume a lot of server memory. Maybe if you cut down your query in smaller subqueries it might improve performance. That way not all tables have to be read in memory and then joined in memory and then filtered and then only the columns you need selected.

Reversing this order will at least save memory, although it doesn't have to improve execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

As DCookie mentioned, both versions should produce identical execution plans.  I would start by looking at the current query's execution plan and figuring out what is actually taking up the memory.  A quick look at DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR output should be a good start.  Once you know exactly what part of the query you are trying to improve, then you can analyze if switching to ANSI style joins will do anything to help you reach your end goal.